# Python - Function - Argument said to be "undefined"

Tags: python, function

I'm currently taking a Python course, and got to the chapter in our book that talks about functions. (Please note, this is my first time learning any programming.)

One of the exercises I'm working on at the moment asks for me to turn a bunch of conditional statements into a function (i.e. generalization).

To make this brief, my problem is this:

After I define a function, let's say like so...

```
def count_letter(letter,string):
    count = 0
    for letter in string:
        count += 1
    print(count)
```

(That is the work, as far as I can recall, for what I typed up for the problem.)

I run the program, then call the function in the shell as usual...

(Example directly below)

```
>>> count_letter(a,bananana)
```

And I get the following output...

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    count_letter(a,bananana)
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

My teacher and everyone in our class can't figure out why we're getting such an error. We would understand if it was some other type of an error, but having the shell tell us an argument is 'undefined' (i.e. a variable, as we understand the error) is something we haven't been able to figure out.

We've been staring at the code for a week and still can't figure it out.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Afterthought: I'm trying to count the number of "a"s within "bananana" in the example. Thought I should clear the ambiguity there.

Comment: Note: your function does not count the occurrences of a given letter in the string, but instead calculates `len(string)`. To solve this, your function parameter and loop variable should have different names, and you should only increment the count if the current character is the same as the function parameter.

Comment: @amon

I agree. I didn't notice that until a few minutes after reading through. Sorry about that.

I changed the code to...
 
    def count_letter(letter,s)
        count = s.count(letter)
        print(count)

Answer (score 3):

As written, `a` and `bananana` are the names of variables which should be defined in a similar way you defined the variable `count`. For example:

```
>>> character_to_search = 'l'
>>> text = 'Hello World'
>>> count_letter(character_to_search, text)
```

would be a correct syntax, because both `character_to_search` and `text` are undefined.

Another possibility is that instead of using actual variables, your intention was to pass strings directly to the function. In this case, your syntax is slightly incorrect. It should be (note the single quotes):

```
count_letter('a', 'bananana')
```

Comment: The second "possibility" is right! :D
Just tried it in the shell.
Thank you, very much. :)